# Firebase Collection returns data but when trying to use the data it returns as [object Object]

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux

I'm trying to make a page where you can read manga. And the problem I have is this when I use `onSnapshot()` and get the data that I need I try to save it in my `ChapterSlice` using `useDispatch()` but when I `consol.log()` my `ChapterSlice` the only thing in it is [object Object]

This is my code

```
const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const { id } = useParams()

  let chapterData

  const getChapters = () => {
    db.collection("Manga").doc(id).collection("Chapters")
    .onSnapshot((snapshot) =>  {
      chapterData = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
        return {id: doc.id, ...doc.data()};
      })  
      console.log("This is the data that I need ",chapterData)
      dispatch(setChapters(chapterData))
    })
  }

  const chapterInfo = useSelector(selectChapters) 

  console.log("this is what I get " + chapterInfo)

  useEffect(() => {
    getChapters()
  }, [])
```

This is my ChapterSlice

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
    chapters: [],
}

const chapterSlice = createSlice({
    name: "chapter",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setChapters: (state, action) => {
            state.chapters = action.payload;
        }
    }
})

export const { setChapters } = chapterSlice.actions;

export const selectChapters = (state) => state.chapter.chapters;

export default chapterSlice.reducer
```

[and this is my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g67Sm.png)

Comment: It's not the issue with data, but with the way you log it, you are adding an object to the string, in console replace the plus `+` with a comma `,`. You logged it correctly when saying what you needed, but incorrectly when chceking what you got.